# How do I load saved states on MyBoy Emulator (Android)?

Tags: android, my-boy

I was playing and saving Pokémon Emerald on Android in Myboy Emulator using the in-game menu, but now I cannot figure out how to load that previous session.

There is no load option in any menu. I can see the file was saved because there is a .sav file.

How can I load it?

Comment: Are you talking a savestate or a real game save (.savs are real saves)? Real saves should be loaded via the ingame menu, savestates via the emulator's menu

Comment: How do you load in game? I can't find any load option in any of the menu.

Comment: It's at the title screen, the "continue" option. There's no load once a save file's already been started if you mean what I think you do

Comment: I'm only getting 2 choices-new game and options no continue

Comment: Got it on another emulator

Answer (score 1):

You cannot load save states in the free version of MyBoy. Make sure you have the full version.

Answer (score 0):

> If you mean states saves, no. For in-game saves, the answer is yes, as long as "the other emulator" uses the common plain save format. Note that the save file name is case sensitive. For example, if your game file is AbCd.gba, then your in-game save must be named AbCd.sav exactly.

https://sites.google.com/site/fastemulator/#TOC-Where-are-the-save-files-Can-I-transfer-them-to-my-new-phone-

Answer (score -2):

That happens to me but I can save it on My Boy Free by saving the game as quick save then when I quick load it, it says that I have to buy premium to load with out an ad if u wait like a couple seconds an ad comes up you cancel it you're back were you liftoff.