# Can I recover a save on MyBoy! Free?

Tags: my-boy

I was just about to start playing my Pokemon Platinum game on *My Boy! Free* on my android, when I accidentally overwrote my save with the title screen. Is there any way of getting back my previous save?

Answer (score 3):

In all likelihood, there is **not** a way to recover saved files that you have already manually overwritten. However, there is a way to check, in case there were backups etc..

If any backups exist, you would need to manually locate them on your device. Some helpful tips can be found at [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/222205/how-do-i-load-downloaded-save-files) which says:

> In "My Boy!," .sav files are actually hidden in the same folders as the roms themselves.

However, you will need to have the full version of *My Boy!* in order to actually load any save games, as mentioned [here.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/167878/how-do-i-load-saved-states-on-myboy-emulator-android)